# Selenium: is there a way to write an xpath to get elements that contains text that ends with numbers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to write an xpath that selects all the elements that contains text which ends with numbers and surrounded by braces. The numbers can be anything and it can be of any number of digits. Is this possible in XPath1.0? I cannot use regex as it is not allowed in XPath1.0

```
<div class = '12345' >
   <div class = '98231'>I want this (101)</div>
   <div class = '98232'>I don't want this 101</div>
   <div class = '98233'>I want this (1)</div>
   <div class = '98234'>I don't want this (10A1)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you've written to solve your problem?

Comment: You can only get all elements and then filter by regex using your code binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath-1.0 you cannot use RegEx'es.
But you can use the `fn:number()` function to check if a given string could be a valid number with the `fn:boolean` function:

```
/div/div[boolean(number(substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),')')))]
```

Obviously, this does only work if there are no other brackets in the string. And it doesn't check if the number in brackets is at the end of the string. To add this further restriction, change the expression to

```
/div/div[not(boolean(string(normalize-space(substring-after(.,')'))))) and boolean(number(substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),')')))]
```

This adds a further predicate to check if there are characters other than whitespace after the `)`. Leading and trailing whitespace between the brackets is automatically removed by the `fn:number()` function.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. I didn't these xpath functions existed at all. Is there a website/documentation available with the details of all the functions of xpath that i can refer to.

Comment: You can always refer to the specs for the function library in [XPath-1.0, XPath-2.0 and XPath-3.0/3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/all/). Google for "XPath functions" and you will find site like [this XPath-1.0 list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions) or [this XPath-2.0 list](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp) which may be easier to read, but are less precise.

Answer (score 0):

Try following xpath:

```
//div//div[text() and contains(text(),'(') and contains(text(),')')]
```